# Calculate Running total over calculated column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculated the running total over a calculated field in SQL Server. I have two columns that look like this:

```
TimeElapsed | CurrentValue
     0      |     0.003
     1      |     0.002
     2      |     0.001
```

I am looking for this:

```
TimeElapsed | CurrentValue |   CummuSum
     0      |     0.003    |     0.003
     1      |     0.002    |     0.005
     2      |     0.001    |     0.006
```

To get the first table, I have written the following query:

```
select 
    floor(datediff(hh,date1,date2)) as TimeElapsed,
    cast(count(date2) as float)/(select count(col3) from table) as CurrentValue 
from 
    table
group by 
    floor(datediff(hh,date1,date2))
order by 
    floor(datediff(hh,date1,date2)) asc;
```

The first statement calculates the difference in time of two separate columns and uses the floor function to remove any minutes or seconds. So If I have a difference of 1 hour and 30 minutes all I care about is the 1 hour. The second statement in the select portion calculates the percentage of items in that range compared to the total number of items. The values in Date2 may be `NULL`.

I thought abut writing a subquery but when I try to sum over the `CurrentValue` column I always get the `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.` error.

Can someone please guide to get the running total?

Comment: what sql-server version are you using?

Comment: In SQL Server 2012+, you can use the window function `SUM() OVER(ORDER BY...` to achieve this, but you would need to put your current query in a subquery first (so you're not trying to perform an aggregate on an aggregate).

Comment: @Tanner It is actually Azure SQL, the database is hosted in the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using SQL Server 2012+, using `SUM()` with the [`OVER() Clause`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) would allow you to achieve a running total.

For example,

```
SELECT TimeElapsed,
       CurrentValue,
       CummuSum = SUM(CurrentValue) OVER (ORDER BY TimeElapsed)
FROM 
(
    SELECT TimeElapsed = DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date1, Date2),
           CurrentValue = CAST(COUNT(Date2) AS FLOAT) / (SELECT COUNT(Col3) FROM myTable)
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date1, Date2)
) T
ORDER BY TimeElapsed;
```

An alternative way of achieving this (which would work in SQL Server 2008), is using a CTE with a subquery in the select statement.

For example,

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TimeElapsed = DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date1, Date2),
           CurrentValue = CAST(COUNT(Date2) AS FLOAT) / (SELECT COUNT(Col3) FROM myTable)
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY DATEDIFF(HOUR, Date1, Date2)
) 
SELECT TimeElapsed,
       CurrentValue,
       CummuSum = (SELECT SUM(CurrentValue) FROM CTE WHERE TimeElapsed <= C.TimeElapsed)
FROM CTE C;
```

Comment: This is close but the results are not quite what I am looking for. How can I group them by the TimeElapsed variable? I tried adding the `group by` clause but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @JuanDaza I edited it to be the same as your query (minus the floor on the datediff since datediff always returns an integer anyway).